# Jenkins Label parameter Issue

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I created 4 slaves in my Jenkins and give a same label "test".Now I want when I will give the test label the deployment should run on all the slaves which is having the label test but unfortunately it is not working.while I give the test label it shows all the nodes which is associated with them but it doesn't execute the job on all slaves just only one.

The first picture shows how I am defining the Label parameter in the jenkins job.it shows Run on all nodes matching the label

[image]

The second pic shows while I am giving test in deployeLayer it shows all the nodes but after executing it this doesn't run the job on all matching nodes.

[image]

Can someone tell me if I am missing something

I am using the below version 
**Jenkins ver.** 1.558
**Node and Label parameter plugin** = 1.5.1

Comment: This question is more suitable for [Software Recommendation](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) stack exhchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin, BuildParameterFactory](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin#NodeLabelParameterPlugin-BuildParameterFactory):

> *The nodelabel parameter plugin also adds a `BuildParameterFactory` to the parameterized trigger plugin, this factory enables you to trigger a build of a specific project on all nodes having the same label.*